# Vaadin BeanItemContainer, making Read Only?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

I've created a static BeanItemContainer and want to make or set it read only. Is this possible to do directly or indirectly?

Comment: As Dragan Radevic pointed out below, the grid does not allow editing by default but you can alter its behaviour by calling `grid.setEditorEnabled(true);`. Alternatively if you're implementing your own container, you can define which [properties](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Property.html) are editable when implementing the `isReadOnly()` method. Also, bean containers will implicitly disable editing for bean properties which have no setter. However, at this point your question is too vague. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

You can set Properties to be read only. So you can iterate through properties and set all properties inside BeanItemContainer to be read only. There is not method on BeanItemContainer for this purpose so you have to do it manually.

Note that [`Table`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html) or [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html) components can be [set to read-only mode](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setReadOnly(boolean)).

Comment: My concern is a Public or Protected static BeanItemContainer where others can call add() or remove() on it (and the various variants).  I tried creating a class that extents BeanItemContainer and called it BeanItemContainerReadOnly where I simply overloaded the Add and Remove methods and throw if their called, but it didn't seem to go very well.

Comment: Extending container is expecting to work. What is problem in your case. Could you explain?

Comment: Probably solution is to create your own container from scracth. Interesting discussion on this topic you can find on the link: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/218547